# Preferences class (java.util.prefs) stores/calls correctly, but XML code doesn't reflect all actions

Tags: java, xcode, plist

When I run the `ClassA.java` code below, the `prefs.get("key2","")` call returns the stored information as expected.  But when I open the actual file(`com.apple.java.util.prefs`) it doesn't show key2 and value2 for the level2 node (see XML content below Java code).

Even stranger, if I remove the `.put("key2", "value2")` method and run it again, it still returns the correct `value2`.  So it's obviously being stored, but why won't any plist editors pick it up?  I used `XCode` and `PlistEdit Pro`.

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ClassA();
    }

    public ClassA() {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("Parent/level1");
        prefs.put("key1", "value1");
        String value1 = _prefs.get("key1", "");
        System.out.println(value1);

        prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("Parent/level1/level2");
        prefs.put("key2", "value2");
        String value2 = _prefs.get("key2", "");
        System.out.println(value2);
    }
}
```

Output

```
value1
value2
```

com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>/</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Parent/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>level1/</key>
            <dict>
                <key>key1</key>
                <string>value1</string>
                <key>level2/</key>
                <dict/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I just discovered the existence of the `Preferences` class thanks to your question XD but did you try to use the [sync](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#sync--) method?

Comment: Antiphon0x I'm glad to have contributed :-)  And yes, though I'm not sure my question was understood.  To be clear, everything works fine.  I can add to any level under the root and retrieve.  The issue is that anything written below the the second sub-level under the root, doesn't show up in either Xcode or the raw XML file as illustrated above. Anyone?